# Exact linear sequences of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

Let
$ 0 \rightarrow  V_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} V_2 \xrightarrow{\phi_2} V_3 \cdots \xrightarrow{\phi_n} V_n $
be an exact sequence of linear maps ($im(\phi_{i-1}) = ker (\phi_i)$ for all i. Show that if all $V_i$ are finite-dimensional then
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^n dim V_i = 0 $

I have being working on this problem and the way I understand it is that if I have a sequence of linear maps like.

$$ 0 \rightarrow  V_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} V_2 \xrightarrow{\phi_2} V_3
\\
0 \rightarrow v_{11} \rightarrow v_{21} \rightarrow 0
\\
0 \rightarrow v_{12} \rightarrow v_{21} \rightarrow 0
\\
0 \rightarrow v_{13} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0
\\
0 \rightarrow v_{14} \rightarrow v_{22} \rightarrow 0
\\0 \rightarrow v_{15} \rightarrow v_{22} \rightarrow 0
\\   \hspace{2cm}  v_{23} \rightarrow v_{31}
\\
 \hspace{2cm}  v_{24} \rightarrow v_{32}
\\
 \hspace{2cm}  v_{25} \rightarrow v_{33}
$$
I constucted this exact sequence of linear maps where $v_{1i}$ is the ith base vector for $V_1$ and $v_{2i}$ is the ith base vector for $V_2$ and so on.
Yet $-5+5+3$ is not equal to $0$ what am I missing?

Thank you very much.
I am note seeking a solution (at least not yet) I just want to understand why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: The missing item is the last arrow $\rightarrow 0$. So you need $$ 0 \rightarrow  V_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} V_2 \xrightarrow{\phi_2} V_3\rightarrow 0.$$ Without the last part it is already false for $n=1$ with $0\rightarrow V_1$.

Comment: Thank you @Dietrich Burde , but I don't really understand what you are trying to say, how does the whole of $V_3$ mapping to zero change the dimension in any way?

Comment: Adding $V_n \to 0$ and requiring that the sequence also be exact at $V_n$ imposes the condition that $\phi_{n-1}$ must be surjective.

Comment: I want to say that your statement is false (so no wonder your computations will not be successful). It claims, for $n=2$, if $0\rightarrow V_1\rightarrow V_2$ is exact, then $\dim(V_1)-\dim(V_2)=0$. This is clearly false. However, in the correct version we have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow V_1\rightarrow V_2\rightarrow 0$. **Then** it works! See also the proof of the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242307/a-question-about-long-exact-sequence-of-finite-dim-vector-spaces?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Also, in your example, the sequence is not exact at $V_1$ because for example $v_{11} - v_{12}, v_{13}, v_{14} - v_{15}$ are in the kernel of the map $V_1 \to V_2$ but not in the image of the map $0 \to V_1$.

Comment: @Real_momo What exactly do you mean when you write $0 \to v_{11}$? The linear map from $0$ to $V_1$ must map $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Oh, Thank you @everyone , the problem was I used to write off the maps $0 \rightarrow A $, the leftmost map and the rightmost map, because they weren't exactly labeled, so I just thought of them as an "aesthetic", but thinking back, that was pretty foolish. 
But oh well, I'm learning
Thank you once again